# How to write this if conditional in PHP?

Tags: php

My variables, `$current` and `$row['start']` are in the format of **2012-07-24 18:00:00**

How should I write the following ?

`if ($row['start'] - $current < 2 hours) echo 'starts soon'`

Additionally is there a way to combine it with the below ?

```
<?php echo ($current > $row['start']) ? 'Started' : 'Starts';  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert those datetime strings into timestamps which you can then add and subtract from eachother.

```
$diff = strtotime($row['start']) - strtotime($current);
if ($diff < 7200) {
    echo 'Starts soon';
} else if ($diff <= 0) {
    echo 'Started';
} else {
    echo 'Starts';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I suppose that there is no way of doing this without converting them to timestamps ?

Comment: No, you can compare date strings in that format using `>`, `<`, and `==`, but you cannot tell the actual difference in time like that.  [DateTime::diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) can also give you the difference, but internally the values are converted to timestamps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest working in seconds (since epoch), which strtotime() is great for:

```
define("SOON_THRESHOLD", 2*60*60); // 7200 seconds == 2 hours
$start_time = strtotime($row['start']);
$current_time = strtotime($current);
$seconds_til_start = $start_time - $current_time;

if($seconds_til_start < SOON_THRESHOLD) {
  ...
}
```